# Logrotate Create Mode Issue

Tags: linux, mongodb, logrotate

I have a trouble with logrotate service in linux.
I have a logrotate config for mongodb log as below:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
{
   rotate 10
   daily
   dateext
   dateformat %Y-%m-%d-%s
   dateyesterday
   missingok
   create 644 mongodb mongodb
   delaycompress
   compress
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
     /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep mongod)
   endscript
}
```

As can be seen, I expect that mode of new mongodb file to be 644 but it is 600 and only the closed log file mode is 644.

`ls -l` command output:

```
total 640
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  9822 May 29 19:42 mongod.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb     0 May 29 19:29 mongod.log.2022-05-29T14-59-01
```

I don't understand what problem is exactly.